# Finding out the number solutions for an equation system.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm currently doing an exercise where I should solve the equation system:

```
ax + y + az = 2
x + ay + z = 2
x + az = 1
```

and then answer "for which values on a does the equation system only have on solution? For which values on a do we have an infinite amount of solutions, and what value on a lacks solutions.

After solving the equation system I got this as an answer:

[image]

Now, how do I solve for which values on a does the equation system only have on solution? For which values on a do we have an infinite amount of solutions, and what value on a lacks solutions.

Comment: Use the fact that you can't divide by zero

Comment: Why is the solution for $x$ written is such a confusing way

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is given by

$$(a-1)^2 (a+1)$$

- When the $\det \ne 0$, we have a unique solution for a fixed $a$.

$$x = \dfrac{1}{a+1},~~ y = \frac{2}{a+1},~~ z = \dfrac{1}{a+1} $$

- When $a = -1$, the RREF yields no solution.
- When $a = 1$, the RREF yields infinite solutions and we have ($z$ is a free variable)

$$\begin{align} y &= 1 \\ x &= 1-z\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: From the last equation we get
$$x=1-az$$ so we get

$$1-az+ay+z=2$$ or
$$z(1-a)+ay=1$$
and with
$$a(1-az)+y+az=2$$ we get
$$y=2-a+a^2z-az$$ we get

$$z(1-a)+a(2-a+a^2z-a^2z)=2$$
Can you finish?

$$z(1-a+a^3-a^2)=2+a^2-2a$$
The last equation is given by $$z(1-a)^2(1+a)=a^2-2a+2$$

Comment: Not really, I've been sitting with Mathematica and doing exercises like this since this morning, so I'm knackered...

Comment: You must factorize $$1-a+a^2(a-1)=(1-a)(1-a^2)$$

Comment: which gives that all values of a are solutions right? But for which values does a only have one solution then? And for what value of do we not have any solutions?

Comment: You can not divide by $$(1-a)(1-a)(1+a)$$ if $$a=1$$ or $$a=-1$$

Comment: Yes. But for which values on a does only one solution exist? And for which values do we not have any solutions?